# KendoUI detail template get the encoded value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I am following kendoUI detail template example from [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/detailtemplate), if you go down the link you will see some thing like "#= Country #" to display the country. How to get this value in razor in if check, When i run the code by commenting the if check and using @GetServerID to display the value, i get the value of it but how to use it in "if". It seems really stupid question but i need some help to figure it out. **Please Not that every thing else is working fine i just need the encoded value "#=...#" in if check.**

```
@using ServerList.Model.Model
@{
    var viewDataServer = (List<ServerDetails>)ViewData["TestData"];
    ViewBag.Title = "Environment";
    Session["Index"] = (Convert.ToInt16(Session["Index"]) + 1);
    int x = 0;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EnvironmentPOCO>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          //columns.Bound(d => d.EnvironmentID).Visible(false);
          columns.Bound(d => d.EnvironmentName).Width(200).Title("Environment Name").Visible(false);
          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.EnvironmentTypeID, (List<EnvironmentTypePOCO>)ViewData["EnvironmentType"], "EnvironmentTypeID", "EnvironmentTypeCode").Width(150).Title("Environment Code").EditorTemplateName("_EnvironmentCodeDropDown");
          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ServerID, (List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["MyServers"], "ServerID", "ServerDetailsProperty").Width(300).Title("Server Details").EditorTemplateName("_ServerDropDown");
          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ProjectID, (List<ProjectPOCO>)ViewData["MyProjects"], "ProjectID", "ProjectDetailsProperty").Width(400).Title("Project Details").EditorTemplateName("_ProjectNameDropDown");
          columns.Command(d =>
          {
              d.Edit();
              d.Destroy();

          }).Width(200).Title("Action");
      }

      )

      .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
      .Sortable()
      .Pageable()
      .Filterable()
      .Navigatable()
      .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
       .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
      .Events(events => events.Change("GetServerID"))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(m => m.EnvironmentID);

            })

            .Read(read => read.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
            .Create(create => create.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
            .Update(update => update.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))
      )

)
```

This is the TabStripCode

```
items.Add().Text("Contact Information").Content(@<div>
                                <ul>

                                @foreach(var Login in viewDataServer)
                                {

                                 var GetServerID="#=ServerID#";

                                  if("#=ServerID#"==Login.ServerID.ToString())
                                    {
                                    @GetServerID
                                    <li><label>UserID:</label>@Login.UserID.ToString()</li>
                                    <li><label>Password:</label>@Login.passwd.ToString()</li>
                                   }
                                }


                                </ul>
                            </div>);
            })
```

Comment: You can use 'data' variable inside detail template. I has current observable object to do the tricks.
#= # syntax is only for rendering values in html. Where actually ServerId is defined? Have you tried data.serverID?

Comment: I tried it and many different things but couldn't get the value in the if check.

Comment: Show some more source code. This looks so simple problem to solve. What is ServerID, is it global variable or observable property etc?

Comment: You have datagrid which shows some information about server environments? So user selects some datagrid row and you want to show credentials in tab based what is selected from datagrid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60498/discussion-between-japi-and-salman-shaykh).

Comment: Did you find a solution?